# A charged conductor NOT in electrostatic equilibrium -- still an equipotential surface?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, non-equilibrium

It is well known that "the surface of any charged conductor **in electrostatic equilibrium** is an equipotential surface" (Serway/Jewett; emphasis mine). I haven't found a good answer online for whether a charged conductor **not in electrostatic equilibrium** is also an equipotential surface.

Take, for example, a busbar at a large substation in active operation. Is this busbar an equipotential surface? If yes, would it have to follow that two transformers (of different turns ratios) connected to the busbar must have the same voltage on the side connected to the busbar?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

Take a monopole antenna as an example. When you drive it with an rf signal you drive it out of equilibrium. Is it were still an equipotential surface it wouldn't produce any rf emission and wouldn't be much good as an antenna.

Comment: I think your answer could be misunderstood if read superficially. In a *short* (Hertzian) electric dipole the two pieces of metal of the radiator have potentials that vary in time as a sinusoid with opposite signs while being driven by a voltage source but on each metal pieces the potential is constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in detail would be No. But it depends on the timescales you care about.

One time scale is the speed of light. If I close a switch that is far away and the electrons move on one part of the circuit, it will take time for the other potions of the circuit to see the change in change in potential.

This is very fast and is illustrated in this [numerical simulation](https://%20American%20Journal%20of%20Physics%2070,%201187%20(2002);%20doi:%2010.1119/1.1508444) below.
[image]

A second time scale is the RC time constant.  Or RL time constant - again if a switch is opened or closed during the transient it will take some time for the current to reach a steady state value and the potential will be changing until that value is reached.

If there was any free charge in the system it would dissipate or move to the surfaces with a time constant related to the conductivity of the material.

However for low frequencies, I think you can argue that you can effectively have a quasistatic situation and that for a given time step you might be able to treat the problem as a series of equipotential solutions.